# Vim shell git returns not a git repository

Tags: git, vim

In vim working on `~/myproject/foo.bar` `:!git commit "/home/myproject/foo.bar" -m "lorem"` returns

```
fatal: "/home/myproject/foo.bar" is outside repository
shell returned 128
```

while on terminal the same command works like a charm

```
/home/myproject/
$ git commit "/home/myproject/foo.bar" -m "lorem"
one file changed
```

Any ideas where I should start digging?

Comment: What is the current working directory of your `vim` session? That is, if you run `:pwd` what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change [the current directory in vim](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#current-directory) either using command `:cd` (changes the current directory globally, for all windows) or  `:lcd` (changes the current directory locally, for the current window only). Or you can change the current directory in the very command:

```
:!cd ~/myproject/foo.bar && git commit foo.bar -m lorem
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read first a [git documentation](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials). You have to add your files first then commit it to the repository.

```
cd /home/myproject/
git add foo.bar
git commit -m "lorem"
```

In your case you try to add a file outside your repo what the error message mentioned.